# git: list all commits made on a branch (--first-parent gives wrong result)

Tags: git

I am trying to list all commits made on a branch in git and suspect that this is impossible to do. Am I right?

Given the following git history:

```
A - B - D  master branch 
  \ C /    dev branch
```

The order of commits:

1. A, initial commit made on master
2. C, made on dev branch
3. B, made on master branch
4. D, merge commit, when merging master into dev
5. D, merge commit, when merging dev into master

When step 5 happens, the master branch tag is moved from B to D.

After step 4, the first parent of D is C. But since the merge in step 5 does not create a new merge commit, only the branch tag is moved, after step 5, the first parent of D is still C.

So when running

```
git log --first-parent master
```

to see the history of master branch, it will list the commits D, C, A. Which is wrong, because C was created on dev branch, not on master.

I am aware that git does not store information which branch was used when a commit was created. It also seems that it is impossible to find out this information from the git history. Does this mean that basically there is *no way* to tell the list of commits made on a branch in git? In this case I would like to see the result D, B, A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Git's answer is "don't do that"

More precisely, you want `git merge --no-ff`.  Do that instead.

Here is your history redrawn in my preferred style:

```
A--B
 \  \
  C--D   <-- dev, master
```

Note that this is identical to the slightly more awkward drawing:

```
A--B--D   <-- dev, master
 \   /
  `-C
```

in terms of what the graph contains: both branch *names* both point to the single commit `D`.  (Aside: neither drawing properly labels which backwards link is first and which is second.  There just isn't enough room in a text graph like this to put in those labels.)  This comes from your steps 4 and 5.  Let's draw what you had at step 3:

```
A--B   <-- master
 \
  C    <-- dev
```

In step 4, you got a real merge commit—and `--no-ff` would have made no difference—because you did `git checkout dev && git merge master`, and there was a common merge-base commit `A` and two differing branch tips `B` and `C` that had to be combined.  So now, after step 4, you have this:

```
A--B   <-- master
 \  \
  C--D   <-- dev
```

In step 5, though—`git checkout master && git merge dev`—you *didn't* get a new commit.  At the time you did that, the common merge base was commit `B`, to which `master` pointed.  The single further-ahead tip commit is commit `D`, to which `dev` pointed (and still points).  So Git does a *fast-forward* operation, moving the name `master` to point to existing commit `D` (and updating the work-tree in the process):

```
A--B
 \  \
  C--D   <-- dev, master
```

If you use `--no-ff`, you tell `git merge` "don't do that"—don't do a fast-forward operation; make a real merge.  Then you get new merge commit `E`:

```
A--B---E   <-- master
 \  \ /
  C--D   <-- dev
```

The first parent of commit `E` is `B`, while the first parent of commit `D` is `C`.  So now `--first-parent` does what you want.